# How to send formData (including file and string data) with files from Vue to Laravel API

Tags: laravel, forms, vue.js, post, file-upload

Please note that each app is hosted on a different server

I'm having a form like this (this is just the most important part of the code not all of it to simplify the problem)

```
<b-form name="import" @submit.prevent="importExcel" inline>
  <b-file id="fileUpload" name="users" :state="Boolean($v.form.usersFile.required)" @change="onFileChange" accept=".xls, .xlsx"/>
</b-form>

methods: {
onFileChange(e){
  //console.log(e.target.files[0]);
  this.form.usersFile = e.target.files[0];
  console.log( this.form.usersFile);
},
importExcel() {

  this.$v.$touch();

  if (this.$v.$invalid) {
    store.dispatch('notification/error', 'Form Error');
    return false;
  }

  var formData = this.gatherFormData();
  console.log(formData);
  userService.importUsers({formData}).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.status === 200) {
      store.dispatch('notification/success', 'Users added to queue for import.');
      return true;
    }

    store.dispatch('notification/error', 'An unexpected error occurred.');
  }).catch(() => store.dispatch('notification/error', 'An unexpected error occurred.'));
},
gatherFormData() {
  const formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append('users', this.form.usersFile);
  formdata.append('images', this.form.imagesFile);

  const json = JSON.stringify({
    unique_fields: this.form.uniqueFields,
    update_duplicates: this.form.duplicateUsers,
    entity_id: this.entityId,
    user_id: this.userId,
  });
  formdata.append('data', json);
  return formdata;
},
},
```

The importUsers service

```
function importUsers(params)
{
  return client.postFormData('/api/users/import', params).then(handleResponse);
}
```

When I check the Request of browser network tab I find:

```
-----------------------------316350962935503659401046831732 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="users"; 
filename="demo_users.xlsx" Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet 
PKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-----------------------------316350962935503659401046831732 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images" null -----------------------------316350962935503659401046831732 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data" {"unique_fields":["email"],"update_duplicates":"ignore",
"entity_id":"xxxx","user_id":"xxxx"} -----------------------------316350962935503659401046831732--
```

And the response is the validation error. The laravel validation can't find any of the parameters sent with the post request. (Please note that everything is working fine using Postman) How can I edit this to send formData containing parameters and files to be uploaded to Laravel and does formData automatically ad `multipart/form-data` to the request to upload files or should I add it manually?

Comment: there should not be `{` and `}` to `userService.importUsers({formData})`

Comment: In the console I get ````[object Object]```` as sent parameters if I use ````{formData}```` and get the same validation error from Laravel

Comment: How have you defined the validation rules?

Answer (score 0):

In component I created a function to create and return formData

```
let formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('users', this.form.usersFile);
formdata.append('images', this.form.imagesFile);

const json = JSON.stringify({
  entity_id: this.entityId,
  user_id: this.userId,
});
formdata.append('data', json)
return formdata;
```

And created this method

```
methods: {
  onFileChange(e){
    this.form.usersFile = e.target.files[0];
  },
```

And this input

```
<b-file id="fileUpload" name="users" @change="onFileChange" accept=".xls, .xlsx"/>
```

In laravel validation request

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'entity_id' => 'required|uuid',
        'user_id' => 'required|uuid',
    ];
}


protected function prepareForValidation() {
    $newData = $this->request->all();
    $data = json_decode($newData['data']);
    $this->merge([
        'entity_id' => $data->entity_id,
        'user_id' => $data->user_id,
    ]);
}
```

And then validate files in the controller

```
if(!$request->file('users')){
  .......
}

$request['data'] = json_decode($request['data']);
.........
```